# Oracle jdbc driver: Constraint [null]

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, wildfly, oracle12c

We are using Oracle 12c for a Java/Spring/Hibernate REST application.  The UI guys forgot to validate that one of the values on their save was not null, so hibernate threw a DataIntegrityViolation.  When this happens locally, the exception stack trace shows me the actual constraint that was violated.  On the test server, the exception shows Constraint [null].

I remember having to jump through some seemingly ridiculous hoops to download and integrate the Oracle jdbc driver with Maven.  Are there any similar hoops for getting the driver to work properly on the server?  My Maven dependency:

```
    <!-- Oracle 12c driver version -->
    <oracle.version>12.1.0</oracle.version>     

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
      <version>${oracle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is a partial stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
could not execute batch; SQL [insert into OMG_TABLE (OMG_CD, CREATED_BY,
CREATED_DT, OMG_DIFFERENCE, FILERENTRY_OMG, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DT,
REMOVAL_OMG, OMG_UOM, OMG_AMT, ADVALOREM_OMG, OMG_ID, LINE_OMG, OMG_CLASS_ID)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested
exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
```

Comment: can you please add here stack trace of exception.

Comment: It just hit me that this probably  depends on configuring the server to use the correct driver.  We are using wildfly-8.2.1, and I don't see *any* oracle-specific configuration in the standalone or module configs.

Comment: The following article explains how to configure Oracle jdbc for wildfly, and none of these steps have been performed.  http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/installing_oracle_jdbc_driver_on